# Need help in To Do List - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

**To Do List JavaScript**

I need code of it.

When you click on a list from "New List" you will see new list in "Done" List. I don't want the "x" after texts in "Done" list. I want to add inputvalue and remove inputvalue in array(var A) when I close a list from "New List". How to do that and where should I place the code?

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}

#Header{
        padding:50px;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
    }
    
#myInput{
         padding:20px;
   width:300px;
   height:auto;
   background-color:black;
   color:white;
   border:2px solid white;
   outline:none;
  }
  
#Add{
     padding:18.5px;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  border:2px solid white;
  outline:none;
  margin-left:;
  margin-top:;
  position:absolute;
  cursor:pointer;
 }

#NL{
    padding:20px;
 font-family:verdana;
 font-size:12pt;
   }
   
#NL2{
     position:absolute;
  left:400px;
  top:160px;
  padding:20px;
  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:12pt;
    }
 
#myUL{
      list-style-type:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width:400px;
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   position:absolute;
  }
  
#myUL li{
       padding:20px 20px 10px 20px;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    border:1px solid white;
    opacity:0.9;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition:0.3s ease-in;
   }
   
#myUL li:nth-child(odd){
                      background-color:black;
       color:white;
       opacity:0.8;
      }
      
#myUL li:nth-child(even){
                      background-color:black;
       color:white;
       opacity:1;
      }      
      
#myUL li.checked{
               text-decoration:line-through;
      opacity:0.4;
               transition:0.3s ease-in-out;      
     }
     
#myUL  li.checked:before{
                       content:"";
                       width:20px;
                       height:10px;
                       border-left:5px solid white;  
                       border-bottom:5px solid white;
                       position:absolute;  
                       transform:rotate(-45deg);        
       }
   
.sp{
    margin-left:0px;
   }
   
.checked .sp{
            margin-left:50px;
     }
     
#myUL .close{
            float:right;
         padding:10px;
         margin-top:-10px;
         margin-right:-10px;
         background-color:white;
         color:black;
         opacity:1;
         cursor:pointer;
        }
   
#myUL .close:hover{
                  background-color:#2196f3;
         color:white;
         opacity:1;
        }
   
#myUL2{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-left:400px;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding:0;
    width:400px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    position:absolute;
   }
   

  
#myUL2 li{
  padding:20px;
     background-color:black;
     color:white;
     border:1px solid white;
     opacity:0.9;
     cursor:pointer;
     transition:0.4s;
    }
   
#myUL2 li:nth-child(odd){
                       background-color:black;
        color:white;
        opacity:0.8;
       }
      
#myUL2 li:nth-child(even){
                       background-color:black;
        color:white;
        opacity:1;
       }

#myUL2 li{
        text-decoration:line-through;
  opacity:0.4;
        transition:0.3s ease-in-out;      
    }
     
#myUL2  li:before{
                content:"";
                width:20px;
                height:10px;
                border-left:5px solid white;  
                border-bottom:5px solid white;
                position:absolute;  
                transform:rotate(-45deg);        
      }
       
.sp2{
     margin-left:50px;
    }
 
#myUL2 .close2{
              display:none;
    }
    
#EText{
       margin-left:60%;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div id="Header">

<input type="text" placeholder=" Type your text" id="myInput"/>

<span id="Add" onclick="newElement()">Add</span>

</div>

<div id="NL">New List</div>

<ul id="myUL">

<li><span class="sp">ASQm<span class="close">&times;</span></span></li>
<li><span class="sp">ASadQm<span class="close">&times;</span></span></li>
<li><span class="sp">ASffffQm<span class="close">&times;</span></span></li>
<li><span class="sp">ASQgeryyyyyyym<span class="close">&times;</span></span></li>
<li><span class="sp">ASQgvvvvvm<span class="close">&times;</span></span></li>

</ul>

<div id="NL2">Done</div>

<ul id="myUL2">

<li><span class="sp2">ASQm<span class="close2">&times;</span></span></li>
<li><span class="sp2">ASadQm<span class="close2">&times;</span></span></li>
<li><span class="sp2">ASffffQm<span class="close2">&times;</span></span></li>
<li><span class="sp2">ASQgeryyyyyyym<span class="close2">&times;</span></span></li>
<li><span class="sp2">ASQgvvvvvm<span class="close2">&times;</span></span></li>

</ul>

<p id="EText"></p>

<script>
var input=document.getElementById("myInput");

var A=[];

var i;

var ul=document.getElementById("myUL");

var list=ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

var ul2=document.getElementById("myUL");

var list2=ul2.getElementsByTagName("li");

var etext=document.getElementById("EText");

var sp=document.getElementsByClassName("sp");

var close=document.getElementsByClassName("close");

for(i=0; i<close.length; i++){

close[i].onclick=function(){

this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display="none";

}

}


ul.addEventListener("click", function(n){

if(n.target.tagName=="LI"){

n.target.classList.toggle("checked");

}



}, false);





function newElement(){

var inputvalue=document.getElementById("myInput").value;

var i;

var createli=document.createElement("li");

var span=document.createElement("span");

span.className="sp";

var span2=document.createElement("span");

span2.className="close";

var closetext=document.createTextNode("\u00D7");

var txt=document.createTextNode(inputvalue);

if(inputvalue==""){
alert("Write something.");
}
else{

if(A.indexOf(inputvalue)>-1){
etext.innerHTML="Already exists";
}
else{

var addlist={

a: ul.appendChild(createli),
b: createli.appendChild(span),
c: span.appendChild(txt),
d: span.appendChild(span2),
e: span2.appendChild(closetext)

}

A.push(inputvalue);

etext.innerHTML="";

}




}

input.value="";

for(i=0; i<close.length; i++){

close[i].onclick=function(){

this.parentElement.parentElement.style.display="none";

}

}



for(i=0; i<list.length; i++){

list[i].onclick=function(){

var ul2=document.getElementById("myUL2");

var i;

var dcreateli=document.createElement("li");

var dspan=document.createElement("span");

dspan.className="sp2";

this.style.display="none";

var addlist2={

a: ul2.appendChild(dcreateli),
b: dcreateli.appendChild(dspan),
c: dspan.innerHTML=this.querySelector(".sp").innerHTML

}

}

}

}



for(i=0; i<list.length; i++){

list[i].onclick=function(){

var ul2=document.getElementById("myUL2");

var i;

var dcreateli=document.createElement("li");

var dspan=document.createElement("SPAN");

dspan.className="sp2";

this.style.display="none";

var addlist2={

a: ul2.appendChild(dcreateli),
b: dcreateli.appendChild(dspan),
c: dspan.innerHTML=this.querySelector(".sp").innerHTML

}

}

}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want the "x" after texts in "Done list"

```
#myUL2 span.close {
  display: none;
}
```

For updating array check this

```js
var input=document.getElementById("myInput");

var A=[];

var i;

var ul=document.getElementById("myUL");

var list=ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

var ul2=document.getElementById("myUL");

var list2=ul2.getElementsByTagName("li");

var etext=document.getElementById("EText");

var sp=document.getElementsByClassName("sp");

var close=document.getElementsByClassName("close");

for(i=0; i<close.length; i++){

close[i].onclick=function(){

this.parentElement.style.display="none";

}

}


ul.addEventListener("click", function(n){

if(n.target.tagName=="LI"){

n.target.classList.toggle("checked");

}



}, false);





function newElement(){

var inputvalue=document.getElementById("myInput").value;

var i;

var createli=document.createElement("li");

var span=document.createElement("span");

span.className="sp";

var span2=document.createElement("span");

span2.className="close";

var closetext=document.createTextNode("\u00D7");

var txt=document.createTextNode(inputvalue);

if(inputvalue==""){
alert("Write something.");
}
else{

if(A.indexOf(inputvalue)>-1){
etext.innerHTML="Already exists";
}
else{

var addlist={

a: ul.appendChild(createli),
b: createli.appendChild(span),
c: span.appendChild(txt),
d: createli.appendChild(span2),
e: span2.appendChild(closetext)

}

A.push(inputvalue);

etext.innerHTML="";

}




}

input.value="";

for(i=0; i<close.length; i++){

close[i].onclick=function(){

this.parentElement.style.display="none";

}

}



for(i=0; i<list.length; i++){

list[i].onclick=function(){

var ul2=document.getElementById("myUL2");

var i;

var dcreateli=document.createElement("li");

var dspan=document.createElement("span");

dspan.className="sp2";

this.style.display="none";

var addlist2={

a: ul2.appendChild(dcreateli),
b: dcreateli.appendChild(dspan),
c: dspan.innerHTML=this.querySelector(".sp").innerHTML

}
console.log(A);
// remove from array
var index = A.indexOf(this.querySelector(".sp").innerHTML);
if (index > -1) {
  A.splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(A);

}

}

}



for(i=0; i<list.length; i++){

list[i].onclick=function(){
console.log(A);
var ul2=document.getElementById("myUL2");

var i;

var dcreateli=document.createElement("li");

var dspan=document.createElement("SPAN");

dspan.className="sp2";

this.style.display="none";

var addlist2={

a: ul2.appendChild(dcreateli),
b: dcreateli.appendChild(dspan),
c: dspan.innerHTML=this.querySelector(".sp").innerHTML

}
}

}
```

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}

#Header{
        padding:50px;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
    }
    
#myInput{
         padding:20px;
   width:300px;
   height:auto;
   background-color:black;
   color:white;
   border:2px solid white;
   outline:none;
  }
  
#Add{
     padding:18.5px;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  border:2px solid white;
  outline:none;
  margin-left:;
  margin-top:;
  position:absolute;
  cursor:pointer;
 }

#NL{
    padding:20px;
 font-family:verdana;
 font-size:12pt;
   }
   
#NL2{
     position:absolute;
  left:400px;
  top:160px;
  padding:20px;
  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:12pt;
    }
 
#myUL{
      list-style-type:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width:400px;
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   position:absolute;
  }
  
#myUL li{
       padding:20px 20px 10px 20px;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    border:1px solid white;
    opacity:0.9;
    cursor:pointer;
    transition:0.3s ease-in;
   }
   
#myUL li:nth-child(odd){
                      background-color:black;
       color:white;
       opacity:0.8;
      }
      
#myUL li:nth-child(even){
                      background-color:black;
       color:white;
       opacity:1;
      }      
      
#myUL li.checked{
               text-decoration:line-through;
      opacity:0.4;
               transition:0.3s ease-in-out;      
     }
     
#myUL  li.checked:before{
                       content:"";
                       width:20px;
                       height:10px;
                       border-left:5px solid white;  
                       border-bottom:5px solid white;
                       position:absolute;  
                       transform:rotate(-45deg);        
       }
   
.sp{
    margin-left:0px;
   }
   
.checked .sp{
            margin-left:50px;
     }
     
#myUL .close{
            float:right;
         padding:10px;
         margin-top:-10px;
         margin-right:-10px;
         background-color:white;
         color:black;
         opacity:1;
         cursor:pointer;
        }
   
#myUL .close:hover{
                  background-color:#2196f3;
         color:white;
         opacity:1;
        }
   
#myUL2{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-left:400px;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding:0;
    width:400px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    position:absolute;
   }
   

  
#myUL2 li{
  padding:20px;
     background-color:black;
     color:white;
     border:1px solid white;
     opacity:0.9;
     cursor:pointer;
     transition:0.4s;
    }
   
#myUL2 li:nth-child(odd){
                       background-color:black;
        color:white;
        opacity:0.8;
       }
      
#myUL2 li:nth-child(even){
                       background-color:black;
        color:white;
        opacity:1;
       }

#myUL2 li{
        text-decoration:line-through;
  opacity:0.4;
        transition:0.3s ease-in-out;      
    }
     
#myUL2  li:before{
                content:"";
                width:20px;
                height:10px;
                border-left:5px solid white;  
                border-bottom:5px solid white;
                position:absolute;  
                transform:rotate(-45deg);        
      }
       
.sp2{
     margin-left:50px;
    }
 
#myUL2 .close2{
              display:none;
    }
    
#EText{
       margin-left:60%;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div id="Header">

<input type="text" placeholder=" Type your text" id="myInput"/>

<span id="Add" onclick="newElement()">Add</span>

</div>

<div id="NL">New List</div>

<ul id="myUL">

<li><span class="sp">ASQm<span class="close">&times;</span></span></li>
<li><span class="sp">ASadQm<span class="close">&times;</span></span></li>
<li><span class="sp">ASffffQm<span class="close">&times;</span></span></li>
<li><span class="sp">ASQgeryyyyyyym<span class="close">&times;</span></span></li>
<li><span class="sp">ASQgvvvvvm<span class="close">&times;</span></span></li>

</ul>

<div id="NL2">Done</div>

<ul id="myUL2">

<li><span class="sp2">ASQm<span class="close2">&times;</span></span></li>
<li><span class="sp2">ASadQm<span class="close2">&times;</span></span></li>
<li><span class="sp2">ASffffQm<span class="close2">&times;</span></span></li>
<li><span class="sp2">ASQgeryyyyyyym<span class="close2">&times;</span></span></li>
<li><span class="sp2">ASQgvvvvvm<span class="close2">&times;</span></span></li>

</ul>

<p id="EText"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

I have made these changes

```
d: createli.appendChild(span2),

this.parentElement.style.display="none";

console.log(A);
// remove from array
var index = A.indexOf(this.querySelector(".sp").innerHTML);
if (index > -1) {
  A.splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(A);
```

Comment: What about adding and removing inputvalue from array(var A) when close a list from "New List"?